# what is the context of a static initializator, and how do I declare a friendship to it?

Tags: c++, c++11, visibility, compile-time, static-initialization

```
class test{
    static const int veryprivate=3;
};

const int anarray[]={test::veryprivate};
```

`g++` smartly points out that `anarray` is neither a function or a member function. Is it possible to fix this code keeping `veryprivate` `private`? C++11 accepted.

Comment: All it gives me is that it's private. I suppose a friended `constexpr` function that returns the value of the member would work.

Comment: Make `anarray` a static member too.

Comment: @Pubby, well, if I could I would.

Answer (score 2):

Make `anarray` an array reference:

```
class test {
    static const int veryprivate = 3;
    friend class animpl;
};
class animpl {
public:
    static const int anarray[] = { test::veryprivate };
};
auto &anarray = animpl::anarray;
```

Comment: If you're going to use C++11 (to get `decltype`), why not `auto&` ?